# I'm not sure if my button class file only works in one GameState

Tags: c#, xna

Here is a class file I have for button creation:

```
class Button
{
    Texture2D buttonTexture;
    Rectangle buttonRectangle;
    Color buttonColour = new Color(255, 255, 255, 255);
    public Vector2 size, buttonPosition;

    public Button(Texture2D newButtonTexture, Vector2 newSize)
    {
        buttonTexture = newButtonTexture;
        size = newSize;
    }

    public void setPosition(Vector2 newButtonPosition)
    {
        buttonPosition = newButtonPosition;
    }

    bool down;
    public bool isClicked;

    public void Update(MouseState mouse)
    {
        buttonRectangle = new Rectangle((int)buttonPosition.X, (int)buttonPosition.Y, (int)size.X, (int)size.Y);

        Rectangle mouseRectangle = new Rectangle(mouse.X, mouse.Y, 1, 1);

        if (mouseRectangle.Intersects(buttonRectangle))
        {
            if (buttonColour.A == 255)
                down = false;
            if (buttonColour.A == 0)
                down = true;
            if (down)
                buttonColour.A += 3;
            else
                buttonColour.A -= 3;
            if (mouse.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed)
                isClicked = true;
        }
        else if (buttonColour.A < 255)
        {
            buttonColour.A += 3;
            isClicked = false;
        }
    }

    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        spriteBatch.Draw(buttonTexture, buttonRectangle, buttonColour);
    }
}
```

Below is how I create the buttons in LoadContent (Ignore the shabby parameters it's just the way I'm currently doing it):

```
btnResume = new Button(Content.Load<Texture2D>("Buttons/button_Resume"), new Vector2(GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width / 1.875f, GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height / 4));
btnResume.setPosition(new Vector2(GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width / 2 - (0.5f*btnResume.size.X), GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height / 3));
btnQuit = new Button(Content.Load<Texture2D>("Buttons/button_Exit"), new Vector2(GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width / 1.875f, GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height / 4));
btnQuit.setPosition(new Vector2(GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width / 2 - (0.5f*btnQuit.size.X), GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height - (GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height / 3)));
```

And this is how I draw the two buttons in the draw function of Game1.cs:

```
case GameState.Menu:
    btnResume.Draw(spriteBatch);
    btnQuit.Draw(spriteBatch);
    break;
```

This all works fine. For some reason however, when doing the same thing for a "Play" button to put on a new game state called "MainMenu", the button doesn't show up (I have tested putting the button code in the game state "menu" and the button does appear, it just won't show when in any other game state other than "menu").

Does anybody know why it won't work? I've remembered to create the button, set the position, and then draw it within the "case GameState.MainMenu" part of the draw function in Game1.cs, so I honestly have no idea why it isn't working. As a side note, I've tried drawing buttons for another game state called "CharacterSelection" and that doesn't work either, HOWEVER it does work if I use spriteBatch.Draw (so I'm pretty sure it's a problem with the button class' draw function.

I can provide screenshots of code or in-game elements, and I'm sorry if the code is messy, I tend to do that a lot. This is my first XNA game and I've not coded in c# much in the past so a lot of this is new to me.

EDIT:
Here are all my gamestates:

```
enum GameState 
{ 
    Opening, 
    MainMenu, 
    CharacterSelection, 
    Countdown, 
    Playing, 
    Menu, 
    Options,
} 
GameState CurrentGameState = GameState.Opening;
```

Opening - Opening cinematic Main Menu - Title Screen basically Character Selection - select what character to play as. Countdown - 3,2,1 GO before the game starts. Playing - Game is active, players are playing e.t.c Menu - Pause menu (opens when esc is pressed) Options - When "Options" is pressed in the pause or main menu (Hasn't been set up yet).

Comment: in the gamestate.mainmenu, are you drawing anything aside from btnResume and btnQuit?

Comment: I draw "btnResume" and "btnQuit" in the "Menu" gamestate only. The program will switch to this gamestate if I press escape whilst in the "playing" gamestate (It's just a simple if statement).

The problem lies with the fact that no other buttons can be drawn outside of the menu gamestate. In the mainmenu gamestate I have there's only: IsMouseVisible = true; btnPlay.Draw(spriteBatch); and that's it. In "Update" I have something that tests if btnPlay is pressed (btnPlay is what would be the play button on the main menu)

Comment: Here are all my gamestates:

enum GameState
{
    Opening,
    MainMenu,
    CharacterSelection,
    Countdown,
    Playing,
    Menu,
    Options,
}

Opening - Opening cinematic
Main Menu - Title Screen basically
Character Selection - select what character to play as.
Countdown - 3,2,1 GO before the game starts.
Playing - Game is active, players are playing e.t.c
Menu - Pause menu (opens when esc is pressed)
Options - When "Options" is pressed in the pause or main menu (hasnt been set up yet)

Comment: oh sorry, i mean the Play button not the btnResume and btnQuit, are you drawing anything aside from play button when the state is in mainmenu?

Comment: When the state is mainmenu, the only two things that happen are that the mouse becomes visible and the button is drawn (but it doesn't show)

Also, I don't have any special bring to front things in draw, so it should be drawing the button on top as it goes off the order of the code

Comment: i thought there are other things that you draw in main menu and they are being rendered on top of button well nvm that, btw what happens when you click the position of where the btnPlay is?

Comment: Absolutely nothing

Comment: But the thing is, I know that gamestate is being run, because the mouse isn't visible when the game starts, but when the gamestate changes, the mouse is visible, so it's something to do with "btnPlay.Draw(spriteBatch);"

Comment: it should at least respond when you clicked in the position where it is in. are you sure that the btnPlay is positioned correctly after you constructed it? check the values you fed into the constructor and setPosition

Comment: yeah I added a bit of debug text and it tells me the x, y, width and height of the button no matter what menu I'm on and I can see that all the values are entered and aren't off the screen. It's so weird...

Comment: can you try to pass the value you fed in btnPlay's constructor and setPosition() to btnResume or btnQuit? if that doesnt help either, its really weird it should be easy to solve.

Comment: I used the parameters that I passed btnPlay to both create it and set its position into btnResume, and when I pressed esc whilst playing, the exact "Play" button popped up in place of btnResume (I commented out the old one). So it's not an issue where it's off the screen or the values I passed were incorrect but it wasnt telling me. It's something to do with the gamestate, because NOT A SINGLE BUTTON will show up on any gamestate other than "menu" - the pause menu.

Comment: hi, can you output what is being assigned to CurrentGameState on every state you have (like going to mainmenu,menu etc.) and check the other part of code that manipulates a button, maybe you have a typo like setting the position of btnResume(or anything) but you accidentally put btnPlay (its my experience)

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I've solved it. Silly mistake by me! Forgot "btnPlay.Update(mouse);" in my update function so it wouldn't work xD

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help, but I've solved it. Silly mistake by me! Forgot "btnPlay.Update(mouse);" in my update function! -__-